# Notebook with Ubuntu 20.04: display not working after grub boot manager

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

The internal display of my Asus laptop (Asus A53T Series) turns off, after booting Ubuntu 20.04. Everything starts fine, but after the grub bootloader, the internal display turns off and stays off forever.

I think, the problem is, that the display BACKLIGHT is simply turned off, because, when I attach an external monitor, I can observe the following:

- I can boot up the OS and login.
- External display shows native resolution.
- Internal display is black (backlight is not turned on either).
- When I open the display settings, I see:

  - Both monitors (internal and external are detected properly, with correct display resolution and labels of the monitors) are shown as activated (turned on)
- The size of the desktop spreads over both screens (I can move with the cursor into the black internal screen, but I cannot see anything)
- This observation applies for using Wayland or XOrg and for using Gnome3 or Mate desktop.

I have tried several commands trying to turn on the internal display, but it did not work (e.g. `xset dpms force on`)

When I boot the operating system with the additional kernel parameter `radeon.modeset=0`, then the internal display works, but it doesn't have the native resolution and no external monitor can be attached. I don't want to use this safe-graphics mode on the long run.

I have also tried different other kernel parameters:

- using `radeon.runpm=0` without `radeon.modeset=0` removes some `dmesg` errors and the GUI starts faster with the external display, but despite of that, nothing changes
- `ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 spec_store_bypass_disable=prctl` does not change the situation
- `acpi=off apm=off` does not solve it
- `nomodeset` does not solve it
- `nouveau.modeset=0` does not solve it
- `amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1` does not solve it
- `noacpi acpi=off` does not solve it
- `radeon.drm=0` does not solve it

Further notes

- The very first Ubuntu 16.04 version works out of the box with the internal display. Additionally, a VGA monitor can be attached and used in parallel.
- Ubuntu 16.04.6 does not work anymore and behaves as above
- Ubuntu 18.04 does not work anymore and behaves as above

What can I do to fix that? In my opinion, it would be fixed, if I could "just" turn on the backlight of the internal display. My assumption is, that everything would be fine this way.

- lshw

```
    description: Notebook
    product: K53TA
    vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
    version: 1.0
    serial: xxx
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=K uuid=0BB3197F-B373-11E0-A18C-14DAE9A007CB
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: K53TA
       vendor: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: xxx
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 206
          date: 07/20/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 22
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: ASU1333S9-4G-ECEWG
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: 26364634
             slot: A1_DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: ASU1333S9-4G-ECEWG
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 8C360336
             slot: A1_DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 2c
          slot: L1 CACHE
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 2d
          slot: L2 CACHE
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 34
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
          slot: P0
          size: 1400MHz
          capacity: 1400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h Processor Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          configuration: latency=32
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
             resources: irq:34 memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:36 memory:feb44000-feb47fff
[...]
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
                resources: irq:35 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fea20000-fea3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea1ffff
[...]
```

- cpuinfo

```
    processor   : 0
    vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
    cpu family  : 18
    model       : 1
    model name  : AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
    stepping    : 0
    microcode   : 0x3000027
    cpu MHz     : 860.192
    cache size  : 1024 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 4
    core id     : 0
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 0
    initial apicid  : 0
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 6
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
    bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2
    bogomips    : 2794.91
    TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb
    
    processor   : 1
    vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
    cpu family  : 18
    model       : 1
    model name  : AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
    stepping    : 0
    microcode   : 0x3000027
    cpu MHz     : 858.983
    cache size  : 1024 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 4
    core id     : 1
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 1
    initial apicid  : 1
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 6
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
    bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2
    bogomips    : 2794.91
    TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb
    
    processor   : 2
    vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
    cpu family  : 18
    model       : 1
    model name  : AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
    stepping    : 0
    microcode   : 0x3000027
    cpu MHz     : 874.440
    cache size  : 1024 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 4
    core id     : 2
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 2
    initial apicid  : 2
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 6
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
    bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2
    bogomips    : 2794.91
    TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb
    
    processor   : 3
    vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
    cpu family  : 18
    model       : 1
    model name  : AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
    stepping    : 0
    microcode   : 0x3000027
    cpu MHz     : 969.754
    cache size  : 1024 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 4
    core id     : 3
    cpu cores   : 4
    apicid      : 3
    initial apicid  : 3
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 6
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt cpb hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
    bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2
    bogomips    : 2794.91
    TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb
```

- loaded radeon firmware

```
 sudo dmesg | grep -E 'drm|radeon' | grep -iE 'firmware|microcode'
[sudo] password for xxx: 
[    4.643875] [drm] Loading SUMO Microcode
[    4.643932] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_pfp.bin
[    4.643956] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_me.bin
[    4.643976] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_rlc.bin
[    4.644235] radeon 0000:00:01.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/SUMO_uvd.bin
[    5.744564] [drm] Loading TURKS Microcode
[    5.744624] radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/TURKS_pfp.bin
[    5.744650] radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/TURKS_me.bin
[    5.744677] radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/BTC_rlc.bin
[    5.744710] radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/TURKS_mc.bin
[    5.744745] radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/TURKS_smc.bin
```

- lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

- xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3046 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
LVDS connected 1366x768+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.01*+
   1280x720      59.97  
   1152x768      59.95  
   1024x768      59.95  
   800x600       59.96  
   848x480       59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```